# Using piezo buzzer to play sounds from a device

Tags: piezo-buzzer

I'm curious to see if it is possible to wire a piezo buzzer to a headphone jack and make it play sound coming from a pc or a phone?

Comment: Do you really mean a piezo buzzer which is an active device, or just the piezo disc itself which is a passive device?

Comment: There were toy "pianos" built using piezo like that years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they make sounds but horribly distorted and tinny.
[image]

https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Flex/p37e.pdf